# Recommendations on Motif scoring functions

Tags: sequence-analysis, motifs

I am searching for specific transcription factor binding locations on DNA, and ranking them according the their scores.

For this, I am in search of a tool or method that can generate motif scores for arbitrary-length DNA sequences (denoted as 'x') using a scoring function Motif_score(x, Motif_M_PWM). The purpose is to calculate motif scores in a moving window fashion along the entire DNA sequence. The 'Motif_M_PWM' parameter typically represents the probability weight matrix (PWM) associated with a specific motif 'M.'

One common method to calculate the motif score for a given short sequence 'x' (which has the same length, n, as the motif itself) is by using the formula:

$motif\_score = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \log\frac{PWM\_Probability(x(k), k)} {0.25}$

In this formula, 'x(k)' represents a specific nucleotide in sequence 'x,' and 'k' denotes the position of the nucleotide in the  PWM and x. The '0.25' term accounts for the random chance of any one of the four nucleotides (A, C, G, T) occurring. I think this scoring method is commonly used by tools like HOMER.

I am curious to know if there are alternative scoring functions or methods (tools besides HOMER) available for calculating motif scores on DNA sequences.